# How to always get the latest value from a Go channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, channel

I'm starting out with Go and I'm now writing a simple program which reads out data from a sensor and puts that into a channel to do some calculations with it. I now have it working as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func get_sensor_data(c chan float64) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)  // wait a second before sensor data starts pooring in
    c <- 2.1  // Sensor data starts being generated
    c <- 2.2
    c <- 2.3
    c <- 2.4
    c <- 2.5
}

func main() {

    s := 1.1

    c := make(chan float64)
    go get_sensor_data(c)

    for {
        select {
        case s = <-c:
            fmt.Println("the next value of s from the channel: " + strconv.FormatFloat(s, 'f', 1, 64))
        default:
            // no new values in the channel
        }
        fmt.Println(s)

        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)  // Do heavy "work"
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the sensor generates a lot of data, and I'm always only interested in the latest data. With this setup however, it only reads out the next item with every loop, which means that if the channel at some point contains 20 values, the newest value only is read out after 10 seconds.

Is there a way for a channel to always only contain one value at a time, so that I always only get the data I'm interested in, and no unnecessary memory is used by the channel (although the memory is the least of my worries)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Channels are best thought of as queues (FIFO). Therefore you can't really skip around. However there are libraries out there that do stuff like this: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-diodes is an atomic ring buffer that will overwrite old data. You can set a smaller size if you like.

All that being said, it doesn't sound like you need a queue (or ring buffer). You just need a mutex:

```
type SensorData struct{
  mu sync.RWMutex
  last float64
}

func (d *SensorData) Store(data float64) {
 mu.Lock()
 defer mu.Unlock()

 d.last = data
}

func (d *SensorData) Get() float64 {
 mu.RLock()
 defer mu.RUnlock()

 return d.last
}
```

This uses a `RWMutex` which means many things can read from it at the same time while only a single thing can write. It will store a single entry much like you said.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Here's a paste of what I have now (for future readers, including myself): https://pastebin.com/21KyfYYV   . One more question: what happens if two processes want to write to the `RWMutex` simultaneously? Does it wait, skip or fail?

Comment: They will queue up. The "first" will grab the lock, set the value and release the lock. The "second" will then grab the lock and change the value and release the lock. This isn't a big deal in this case as they are simply setting a value. The lock is only held for a finite amount of time. Where this can get dangerous if you lock and do something that can take a while (writing to a file or something).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've got one more question: I found I can read out the value of `last` using `d.last` or using `d.Get()`. Is there any advantage using `d.Get()` over `d.last`?

Comment: If you read d.last directly you don't use the mutex and have a race

Comment: and with `have a race` you mean it could cause trouble if it is written to and read from at the same time? Or could a race condition also exist when two parts read from it at the same time?

Comment: by a race I mean a data race. A data race occurs when two threads attempt to access memory at the same time. A data race makes your program invalid and can have unpredictable results.

Comment: The existing code uses a unbuffered channel. Won't that already block further write till the value has been read from it? i.e `ch <- 2.1` will need to be read before `ch <- 2.2` can be written to it. So in a sense one is getting latest data from the channel which may not the latest from the sensor.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being slow, but I don't see the code you are referring to (that uses channels).

That being said, the code above (which doesn't use channels) does in fact overwrite old data and only persists the latest.

Answer (score 6):

No. Channels are FIFO buffers, full stop. That is how channels work and their only purpose. If you only want the latest value, consider just using a single variable protected by a mutex; write to it whenever new data comes in, and whenever you read it, you will always be reading the latest value.

Answer (score 1):

Channels serves a specific purpose. You might want to use a code that is inside a lock and update the variable whenever new value is to be set.

This way reciever will always get the latest value.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get that from one channel directly, but you can use one channel per value and get notified when there are new values:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type LatestChannel struct {
    n    float64
    next chan struct{}
    mu   sync.Mutex
}

func New() *LatestChannel {
    return &LatestChannel{next: make(chan struct{})}
}

func (c *LatestChannel) Push(n float64) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    c.n = n
    old := c.next
    c.next = make(chan struct{})
    c.mu.Unlock()
    close(old)
}

func (c *LatestChannel) Get() (float64, <-chan struct{}) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    n := c.n
    next := c.next
    c.mu.Unlock()
    return n, next
}

func getSensorData(c *LatestChannel) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    c.Push(2.1)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    c.Push(2.2)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    c.Push(2.3)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    c.Push(2.4)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    c.Push(2.5)
}

func main() {
    s := 1.1

    c := New()
    _, hasNext := c.Get()
    go getSensorData(c)

    for {
        select {
        case <-hasNext:
            s, hasNext = c.Get()
            fmt.Println("the next value of s from the channel: " + strconv.FormatFloat(s, 'f', 1, 64))
        default:
            // no new values in the channel
        }
        fmt.Println(s)

        time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond) // Do heavy "work"
    }
}
```

If you do not need the notify about new value, you can try to read [Channels inside channels pattern in Golang](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/channels-inside-channels-pattern-in-golang-3d0e73a545cc).

Answer (score -1):

Try this package https://github.com/subbuv26/chanup

It allows the producer to update the channel with latest value, which replaces the latest value. And produces does not get blocked. (with this, stale values gets overridden).
So, on the consumer side, always only the latest item gets read.

```
import "github.com/subbuv26/chanup"
ch := chanup.GetChan()
_ := ch.Put(testType{
    a: 10,
    s: "Sample",
})
_ := ch.Update(testType{
    a: 20,
    s: "Sample2",
})
// Continue updating with latest values
...

...
// On consumer end
val := ch.Get()
// val contains latest value
```

Comment: val will be interface{} type, so type convert it to the desired type.

Answer (score -1):

There is an elegant channel-only solution. If you're OK with adding one more channel and goroutine - you can introduce a buferless channel and a goroutine that tries to send the latest value from your channel to it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func wrapLatest(ch <-chan int) <-chan int {
    result := make(chan int) // important that this one i unbuffered
    go func() {
        defer close(result)
        value, ok := <-ch
        if !ok {
            return
        }

    LOOP:
        for {
            select {
            case value, ok = <-ch:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
            default:
                break LOOP
            }
        }

        for {
            select {
            case value, ok = <-ch:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
            case result <- value:
                if value, ok = <-ch; !ok {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    return result
}

func main() {
    sendChan := make(chan int, 10) // may be buffered or not
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        sendChan <- i
    }
    go func() {
        for i := 10; i < 20; i++ {
            sendChan <- i
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
        close(sendChan)
    }()
    recvChan := wrapLatest(sendChan)
    for i := range recvChan {
        fmt.Println(i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }

}
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I think this implementation doesn't quite work. For example, if there already are several items in the channel before we call wrapLatest(), we'd expect to get the newest of these items, but instead we get one of the oldest. https://go.dev/play/p/bPr-EFlOQks I guess we could add another loop after the initial `value, ok := <-ch` to make sure we drain the channel. But I tried a few approaches and failed to find one that works reliably. I'm not sure it's even possible to do this with channels. (Which I think shows Go that channels are not designed very well.)

Comment: Yes, you're right, one more loop needed to skip the existing values in the channel. I agree that possibly solution with the value under a lock is a more proper one

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to solve this problem (trick)

**sender work faster: sender remove channel if channel_length > 1**

```
go func() {
    for {
        msg:=strconv.Itoa(int(time.Now().Unix()))
        fmt.Println("make: ",msg," at:",time.Now())
        messages <- msg
        if len(messages)>1{
            //remove old message
            <-messages
        }
        time.Sleep(2*time.Second)
    }
}()
```

**receiver work slower:**

```
go func() {
    for {
        channLen :=len(messages)
        fmt.Println("len is ",channLen)
        fmt.Println("received",<-messages)
        time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
    }
}()
```

OR, we can delete old message from receiver side
(read message like delete it)